# Unusable USB-C Hub in monitor Dell P2723DE with Ubuntu 2204

Tags: drivers, usb, display, usb-c

I have got Dell P2723DE with usb hub, PD3 etc.. but when I plugged in Lenovo laptop with ryzen 5800u and vega integrated graphics it disconnected few times while setting it up. After finishing setup it was working properly but for like 30 seconds max and after mouse click or some other random event it disconnected again and reconnected and continued with this behavior until I got mad and put it through hdmi cable.

I had to disconnect even usb accesories from monitor because it kept disconnecting, and in the end, i had to use power cable so I can use usb-c cable for charging my phone :).

Does somebody has the same issue? I'll try to check new 2210 ubuntu after I get usb flash.

Update (because I made an assumption)
In windows it doesn't work either. Windows installed automatically some Dell Display 1.0.0.0 driver, which resolved nothing. It works for few seconds and starts almost the same process of flickering like in linux.

Comment: Is the problem with the hub or with video over USB-C? Have you confirmed the cable is capable of the task you’re asking if it? 

Comment: yes, I had it in dell laptop and it was working normally, and i had almost identical lenovo display connected to my lenovo and it was also working normally..  (update: it's not even working in windows - i made an assumption previously)

Comment: its just I don't know.. combination of laptop and that monitor.. some bad implementation probably in laptop or bad implementation in monitor and missing failsafe in laptop which is in dell laptop.. don't know..

Comment: if it is not working on windows, i would think it is an issue with the cable or the port